# PowerShell Core Script deployed as AWS Lambda function fails to remote connect into Windows EC2 Instance using the Commandlet new-pssession

Tags: aws-lambda, powershell-remoting, powershell-core

AWS Recently announced Lambda Support for PowerShell Core. 
Reference URL https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-lambda-support-for-powershell-core/

Followed the steps given in the URL and deployed below Powershell Core script as a Lambda Function.

Script:

```
#Requires -Modules @{ModuleName='AWSPowerShell.NetCore';ModuleVersion='3.3.335.0'}

$pw = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String "Password"
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "UserID",$pw

$s = new-pssession -computername "AWSECS2DNS" -credential $cred

Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Get-Service}
```

When I trigger the Lambda function it fails. This Powershell script tries to remote connect a Windows EC2 Instance and run Commandlet "Get-Service". It fails at the Commandlet "new-pssession". Same script runs fine in Windows Computer powershell. But fails when run as AWS Lambda function. This happens as AWS Lambda function runs in Linux environment. Please help.

Error:

```
{
  "errorType": "DllNotFoundException",
  "errorMessage": "Unable to load shared library 'libpsrpclient' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibpsrpclient: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at Amazon.Lambda.PowerShellHost.PowerShellFunctionHost.ExecuteFunction(Stream inputStream, ILambdaContext context)",
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked with the AWS support team and got the following response:

"After further testing, Lambda service team has confirmed that New-PSSession is currently not supported in lambda environment. This has to do with the way PS Remoting works on PowerShell core for Linux."

Apparently it's a feature on the roadmap, so we may see it *eventually*.

Comment: I didn't. It isn't supported, as I mentioned above. I ended up using a non-lambda approach instead.

Comment: Any idea if this feature is implemented? I'm in need of doing something similar and wondering if i can achieve with Lambda? I did post a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61072978/aws-lambda-powershell-to-create-mailbox-in-hybridrun-powershell-commands-in-bot