# AWS Lambda Powershell to create mailbox in Hybrid(run powershell commands in both Office 365 and On-Prem)

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-lambda, office365, powershell-core

Now that AWS Lambda supports PowerShell core according to this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-lambda-support-for-powershell-core/), has anybody tried running PowerShell commands to create Mailbox in Hybrid env(run PS cmdlets in both On-prem and office 365 env) using lambda? I couldn't find anything online which does that. Most of the Lambda Powershell usecases seems to be related to using PowerShell scripts to automate and manage AWS resources.
I'm working on a POC for a REST service which does all of the mailbox creation operations and was planning to use API gateway to invoke lambda powershell.

I did setup my environment following aws [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-lambda-support-for-powershell-core/) and created a PowerShell script which performs mailbox operation and created and deployed lambda. Upon testing, i'm getting the following errors while creating a PowerShell session for O365 env.

Script snippet:

```
    $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $mycreds -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Write-Host "Created session for PS"
Import-PSSession $Session
Write-Host "Imported Session"
Write-Host "Getting Mailbox"
Get-Mailbox -Identity 'mailbox'
```

Cloudwatch Logs:

```
[Error] - This parameter set requires WSMan, and no supported WSMan client library was found. WSMan is either not installed or unavailable for this system.
[Information] - Created session for PS
[Error] - Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
[Information] - Imported Session
[Information] - Getting Mailbox
[Error] - The term 'Get-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Wondering if anyone has tried invoking Office 365/on-prem mailbox creation PS scripts using lambda or point me to the right direction? Thanks

I would also like to know, if with AWS lambda powershell core can i winrm into another windows box so that i can execute powershell mailbox commands? According to the [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654841/powershell-core-script-deployed-as-aws-lambda-function-fails-to-remote-connect-i) dated in 10/2018 we cannot, but wondering if anyone knows anything latest on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am working the same task.  API->Lambda->C#/PowerShell->Office360->CreateMailbox.
However I'm hung up on the same line as well, but slightly different message.

What do you have for a Requires line in your ps1 file?

```
Requires -Modules @{ModuleName='AWS.Tools.Common';ModuleVersion='4.0.5.0'}
```

I am assuming you are using ModuleVersion='3.3.618.0' per the linked blog post, but there is a '4.0.5.0' version available. ... *However it hasn't help me yet, but perhaps it would help you.*  Here is link with the upgrade information. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/v4migration.html

Comment: I'm using 4.0.5.0 as well. According to https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/368 we cannot achieve that with Lambda. I'm going in an alternate path of API->Lambda->SSM Doc->SSM Run command->PS on Win Ec2 instance. Not ideal but i think this will work.

Comment: Sadly I found similar posts.  The only successful story is captured here, https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=940410#940410.  However, I have yet to duplicate that success story.  I can't seem to get my hands on those missing libraries.

Comment: I saw that post earlier, in my case those dependencies were already getting packaged together. More over i did not see the error "Unable to load shared library 'libpsrpclient' or one of its dependencies". It was more of a "This parameter set requires WSMan, and no supported WSMan client library was found." Let me know if you figure it out. Good Luck